# loops for values in between rows with a certain value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

For the example data in the "A" column:

(Column 1)
D
1
2
3
4
B
3
5
1
C
D
1
2

I would like to write a code does something to the rows that are in between the letters.

I'm thinking  I need to do a for loop that goes down the entire column and finds the letters.

Problem is: Within that loop I want to perform another loop that stops at the next letter. So in the example... the code will be performed for the rows or integers that are between D and B, B and C, C and D.

Can someone please help me on how you would approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the simple loop below should do the job for you.

```
For i = 1 to Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlUp).Row
  IF isNumeric(Range("A" & i)) THEN 
    'Do SOmething Here for the Numbers
  ELSE
    'Do something if there are letters.
  END IF
next i
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. My example is a simplified example of a larger code. I would like to group the letter with all subsequent numbers and do something with it. so for example: the code would apply for rows containing the D 1 2 3 4 and B 3 5 1 and C and D 1 2

Comment: You would need to be specific with the rows and the data in it. Or the sequence of the same.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I wouldn't know the row number at which the next letter will be found.